# Pentaho "Couldn't get row from result set" error

Tags: mysql, pentaho, pentaho-spoon

When I run this query on my MySql client (DBVisualizer) it runs. (It functions and works 100%)

```
SELECT
    MAX(birth_date) AS max_bd
INTO
    @bd_max 
FROM
   employees.birthdays
WHERE
    gender= 'male';
```

When I run it in Pentaho, in a "Execute SQL script" I get this error

```
2018/11/04 10:44:08 - job_update_birthdays - ERROR (version 7.1.0.0-12, build 1 from 2017-05-16 17.18.02 by buildguy) : An error occurred executing this job entry : 
2018/11/04 10:44:08 - job_update_birthdays - Couldn't get row from result set
2018/11/04 10:44:08 - job_update_birthdays - ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data.
```

P.S. I am using the same credentials for both Pentaho and my Mysql client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a command that doesn't acutally returns data. In SQL, the INTO command will copy the data from the SELECT, INTO another table, what SQL is doing is probably just showing you the data that was copied to the target table.

Remove the INTO @bd_max clause from the query and run it.